# Why does the post increment operator not increment the actual value of stored at an integer pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling

I have the following code :

```
#include<iostream>
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;
void Increment(int* a)
{
    *a++;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 8;
    int& ref = a;
    ref = 2;
    Increment(&a);
    LOG(a);
}
```

On running the executable, however, the output is 2 and not 3. I understand that *(pointer) gives the value stored at the pointer and (operand)++ increments the value of the operand and stores it in the memory address of the operand itself. So, what is the exact cause of this unexpected result ?

***COMPILER USED*** :

g++ (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 10.2.0

Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

==========================================================================================

***BUILD COMMAND USED*** :

D:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g D:\programming\cpp\cherno\references\Main.cpp -o D:\programming\cpp\cherno\references\Main.exe

NOTE : I was using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzoFn3dfsPA&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=17) video while learning and on the machine of the guy who was explaining, *a++ worked fine.

Comment: should be `(*a)++`

Comment: `*a++`  is equivalent to `*(a++)`.    The behaviour you seek is `(*a)++`

Comment: @Peter thanks but what I now don't understand is whether this precedence issue is only in gcc compilers or in msvc as well ? because the guy in the youtube video did it *a++ and it worked for him ? do i need to read the compiler specs or something to get a hang of this issue ?

Comment: You misunderstood that video. Starting at 5:30 he is very clear about how to write the correct code. There's nothing wrong with the compiler...

Comment: @Blastfurnace you saved my day. Thanks a ton! I didn't get it that after 5:30 he moved on to the other topic.

Comment: The "precedence issue" is not compiler specific.  The precedence and associativity of all operators is the same for all implementations (i.e. compilers) that comply with the standard.

Comment: Yeah, @Peter. Someone pointed it out above. I had missed a portion of the video.

Comment: @Blastfurnace why is this question closed due to not reproducible or typos ? I am sure there is nothing wrong. As for reproduction, https://godbolt.org/z/ba8jrr is a perfectly working example.

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the rules of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), your expression is interpreted as

```
void Increment(int* a)
{
    *(a++);
}
```

i.e. you increment a pointer, not it's value. You need to add parantheses:

```
void Increment(int* a)
{
    (*a)++;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ba8jrr